# Should there be an apostrophe?

Tags: grammar, sentence, apostrophe

Should there be an apostrophe after transfers in the sentence below.

"Once the Form A Freehold Transfers have been returned to our office."

Comment: Please clarify why you think there should be. (And it's not a sentence unless you have a main verb.)

Comment: When one attempts to use apostrophe for plural, my first instinct is to ask "The [noun]'s *what*?" See: "Banana's on sale: 20c each" "Banana's what?"

Answer (score 1):

No, why would you think there should be?

Apostrophes are used only for possessives and for contractions like *He's* ( = *he is*). Never for plurals (except, according to some people, for pluralising non-words like "All the A's").

None of these cases applies here, which is a simple plural "Transfers".

Answer (score 1):

You have a case of plural vs possessive.   An apostrophe would be needed to denote possessiveness (or ownership) but in this case it looks like you are talking about about many transfers which is plural. If it was possessive then you might say "the transfer's paper was yellow", meaning the paper the transfer is written on is yellow.

Also, you have a sentence fragment there, if you take the word "Once" out then the sentence would be complete.  Or you could add a comma behind "office" and say what's going to happen when the transfers get to the office.  For instance: "Once the Form A Freehold Transfers have been returned to our office, they will be processed."

Answer (score 0):

No. *Transfers* is not a possessive or a contraction, so no apostrophe is needed.

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp